# Remote actor selection stops working when I give the system a blank configuration

Tags: scala, akka

I am using the following configuration for a system that has remote actors I want to connect to:

```
akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = DEBUG
    debug {
        lifecycle = on
        receive = on
    }
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        warn-about-java-serializer-usage = false
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
            hostname = "myhost"
            port = 2561
            maximum-frame-size = 256000b
        }
    }
}
```

Then I do the following to connect to it from my local system:

```
val system = ActorSystem("Test")
val actor = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://remote@myhost:2561/user/myActor")
```

I can send and receive messages to and from the actor no problem. However if I define a blank configuration:

```
akka-test {
}
```

And now define my system as:

```
val system = ActorSystem("Test", config.getConfig("akka-test")
```

Suddenly I can no longer connect to the remote actor. I get the following error:

> Remote actor with path akka.tcp://remote@myhost:2561/user/myActor is
> not available

Why is a blank configuration breaking my ability to connect to the remote system?

NOTE. I am not actually using a blank config but I eventually figured out it was my config that was causing the problem. So I stripped out all config settings to discover the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding RemoteActorRefProvider to my config:

```
akka-test {
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
  }
}
```

I see now that this is specified in the documentation but the fact that it works without setting any configuration is a bit of a curve ball

Comment: What do you mean "works without setting any configuration"?  If you mean that the `ActorSystem` spins up even if `akka.actor.provider` isn't explicitly set, it's defaulted via `reference.conf` to `local`, and classic remoting (note that classic remoting is deprecated and will be removed) requires that to be set to `remote` (which is synonymous with `akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider`).